# Convert dataframe types to Python types or just a way to serialize

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to take a generic dataframe (just an example):

```
my_data_frame = pandas.dataFrame({"numeric":5}, index=[0])
```

and just get `[{"numeric": 5}]`, then serialize it and send it over the wire.

I tried doing this:

```
values = my_data_frame.to_dict('records')
```

which does convert it to `[{"numeric": 5}]`, but the 5 is an 'numpy.int64', and isn't serializable. Is there some way I can get a dataframe into this format, but with Python types instead of Numpy types, and in a generic enough way it works for all dataframes (may have strings or datetimes instead of numeric)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the data frames' `to_json` method which directly converts the data frame to json, so you don't have to worry about the serialization process:

```
my_data_frame.to_json(orient="records")
# '[{"numeric":5}]'
```